# How do I define multiple variables from cin and getline?

Tags: c++, cin, getline

```
    cout << "Please enter your date (mm_dd_yyyy" << endl;
    getline(cin, month, day, year);
```

How do I define several variables (in this case 3) using cin? My homework assignment requests me to be able to get the variables if I type in something such as: "6 10 1973". Anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: You're not "defining" any variables here. If you know how to read one variable at a time, what's stopping you from reading three in a row?

Comment: Are you trying to declare the variables exactly when you read them from the input?

Comment: @john no, they can use spaces to separate them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems simple enough

```
int month, day, year;
cin >> month >> day >> year;
```

PS you don't *define* variables using `cin`. The variables were defined when you wrote `int month, day, year;`. `cin >>` *assigns* values to variables by reading from the standard input.